# C programming error in stack around variable grade

Tags: c

Can you please help me? After i run this code and works fine but at the end i got run time error. My code runs perfectly buy at when i debug i get message like stack around variable grade is corrupted.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define N 4
int main()
{
    int i , j=1,location,x=1;
    float grade[N] , total = 0 , average , max;
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
    printf("\nPlease enter grade : ");
    scanf("%f",&grade[i]);
    total = total+grade[i];
    }
    system("cls");
    printf("\nStudent     Grade");
        for(i=0;i<=N;i++)
        {
        printf("\n%d           %.1f",j,grade[i]);
        j++;
        }
    average = ((total / 500) * 100);
    printf("\n--------------------");
    printf("\nAverage Grade: %.2f ",average);
    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        if(grade[i] > average)
        {
            location=x+i;
            max = grade[i];
            printf("\n\nstudent #%d is above the average and value is %.1f",location ,max);
        }
    }
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your for loops are going from 0 to 4, it should be `for (i=0;i<4;i++)` otherwise you go out of bounds of the array.

Comment: It's best to give N a more meaningful name, like MAX_GRADES, and use it in the for loop as well: `for (i = 0; i < MAX_GRADES; i++)`

Answer (score 1):

All your i<=4 should be i < 4. Or change N to 5